# Magento : Reorder item with custom price, price always 0

Tags: magento

I have some product that has custom prices. Depending on the option selected, there is a formula applied that add fees to the product, so the price is never the same. The problem I have is that when you reorder, the price of the reordered product is always 0.

In sales/controllers/OrderController , in the function reorder,there is this :

```
$order = Mage::registry('current_order');
$items = $order->getItemsCollection();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    try {
        $cart->addOrderItem($item);
        ...
```

If I add these lines , I’m able to retrieve the custom price, but I can’t find a way to edit the item so that is the price being added in the reorder.

```
$options = $item->getProductOptions();
$options = $options['info_buyRequest'];
$customPrice = $options['custom_price'];
```

There is what I have tried (in the loop, before $cart->addOrderItem($item) ), without success.

```
$item->setSpecialPrice($customPrice);
$item->setCustomPrice($customPrice);
$item->setOriginalPrice($customPrice);
$item->setBaseOriginalPrice($customPrice);
$item->setBaseCost($customPrice);
$item->setBaseRowInvoiced($customPrice);
$item->setRowInvoiced($customPrice);
$item->save();
```

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several possibilities. I'd try an event observer for the `checkout_cart_product_add_after` event.

```
// observer method:
public function checkoutCartProductAddAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $action = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction();
    if ($action->getFullActionName() == 'sales_order_reorder')
    {
        $buyInfo = $observer->getQuoteItem()->getBuyRequest();
        if ($customPrice = $buyInfo->getCustomPrice())
        {
            $observer->getQuoteItem()->setCustomPrice($customPrice)
                 ->setOriginalCustomPrice($customPrice);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this, but where is your $item coming from?

Comment: Ups, I'm sorry, that would be `$observer->getQuoteItem()`. I updated the example code.

Comment: Yeah , I figured it out juste before your answer, and it is working fine. Thank you so much!